# Django 1.11 - make column foreign key without deleting

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Previously we made integer field like:

```py
cart_id = models.IntegerField(_('cart_id'), null=True)
```

But now I want to make this field foreign key:

```py
cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, db_column='cart_id')
```

The problem is that in the migration it generates two operations for deleting field and creating new one:

```py
    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='order',
            name='cart_id',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='order',
            name='cart',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column=b'cart_id', to='cart.Cart', null=True),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

Is there any way to make it as alter field?

Comment: Try and call `cart` `cart_id` instead.

Comment: @DMalan It worked, but in this case I need to call this object as `Order.cart_id`. Is there any way to make it `Order.cart`?

Answer (score 1):

First add the `ForeignKey`. Set the default `blank=True` and run migrations.

Then run this code to fill the previous instances (python manage.py shell):

```
m = Order.objects.all()
for i in m:
    c = Cart.object.get(id=i.cart_id)
    i.cart = c
    i.save()
```

Once done check if the `ForeignKey` is filled in the admin.
You can remove `blank=True` in `ForeignKey` it is a required field.